# How to fetch & show only date on invoice not time

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hi we have invoice concept on our website so at the time of invoice creation we are entering both invoice creation date & time & it is entering in this form in db 2014-05-02 21:53:25 but now what I want to show only date 2014-05-02 to client.
Currently in view file of cakephp I am using  `<td><?php echo ($invoice['Invoice']['created']); ?>`  so its is showing whole value of data field which has both date & time combine but I want only date to show so for it I tried

```
 `<?php echo date($invoice['Invoice']['created']); ?>`
```

but its not working can any one help me what function should I use to just show date according to my new format.Thanks!

Comment: try mysql [date_format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: `<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice['Invoice']['created'])); ?>` Try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, using cakephp [Time helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html)

```
<?php echo $this->Time->format('Y-m-d',$invoice['Invoice']['created']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime($invoice['Invoice']['created']));
```